# Visual Studio wants to delete git subtree

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I have a git repository with a subtree that was added with

```
git subtree add --prefix Agate git@github.com:eylvisaker/AgateLib.git master
```

The problem is that Visual Studio wants to delete all these files. If I go ahead and commit, all these files will be deleted and the subtree is removed from the repo. However, `git status` shows `nothing to commit, working directory clean`. SourceTree also shows that there is nothing edited in the working copy. If I allow VS to commit the deleted files they get deleted from the repo. I can re-add the subtree but then VS still wants to delete it.

[image: Visual Studio marks files as to-delete]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with its built-in git support. This happened after switching from submodules to using a subtree. I don't think that's relevant but maybe I'm wrong. My .git/config is listed below. I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = c:/devel/Games/Zodiac/zodiac-test
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

How can I make Visual Studio not want to delete those files, and instead just allow me to edit/commit them as if they were part of this repository, as git subtree is supposed to allow me to do?

Comment: What's in your Changes window?

Comment: The Changes window shows all those files with strike-through, indicating that VS is going to delete them if I commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `.gitmodules` from when I was using submodules was left over, and causing the problem. Executing `git rm .gitmodules` resolved the problem. Visual Studio immediately noticed the change and decided it no longer wanted to delete my subtree.

Comment: Thanks for following up, I've logged a bug to take a look at how we can improve this.